# (Bottom) toolbar navigation no longer responds after upgrade to Xcode 9.0.1 (& Swift 3 to 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, toolbar

Below are two depictions of a WKWebView displaying text from Act 2, Scene 1, of a play. The depiction to the right is after a tap gesture summons, at the top, both a status bar and a navigation bar (which includes a back arrow to the table of contents and text size controls) and, at the bottom, a toolbar with arrows, one to show the previous scene (Act 1, Scene 3) and one to show the next scene (Act 2, Scene 2).

[image: Two depictions of a WKWebView displaying text from a play. The right depiction is after a tap gesture summons a status bar and a navigation bar to the top and a toolbar to the bottom]

Everything apparently was working fine. But after I recently upgraded to Xcode 9.0.1 (and from Swift 3 to Swift 4), the navigation system in the (bottom) toolbar no longer functions in my iPhone 6 running iOS 11.0.3 (THOUGH everything WORKS FINE in the SIMULATOR (iPhone 6 /  iOS 11.0)) and now responds as if a tap gesture were being made in the middle of the view away from the (bottom) toolbar, whereas before the (bottom) toolbar was properly unresponsive to any touches except on the left-pointing and right-pointing triangles to change the scenes. The status bar and the navigation bar still behave as desired as before.

I created the (bottom) toolbar programmatically and thought I had to bring it in front of the WKWebView to get it to work. Here is what I've tried to fix this:

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: toolbar!)
```

But that did not work. And I tried:

```
toolbar!.layer.zPosition = 1
```

But neither did that work. Someone suggested that the problem might be related to the "safe area" in iOS 11, but I am unsure how to address that. I would appreciate your kind help.

Here is the function that creates the (bottom) toolbar:

```
    // Create (bottom) toolbar and items (buttons and text).
func createToolbar() {

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-44, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44)
    toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: frame)
    toolbar?.sizeToFit()
    toolbar?.isHidden = true
    triangleLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "triangleLeft_15x20"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(showPrevious))
    triangleLeftText = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\(String(describing: "previous"))", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    let flexibleSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.flexibleSpace , target: self, action: nil)
    triangleRightText = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\(String(describing: "next"))", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    triangleRightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "triangleRight_15x20"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(showNext))

    if (triangleLeftText?.isEqual(""))! {
        triangleLeftButton?.isEnabled = false
    } else if (triangleRightText?.isEqual(""))! {
        triangleRightButton?.isEnabled = false
    }

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(triangleLeftButton!)
    items.append(triangleLeftText!)
    items.append(flexibleSpacer)
    items.append(triangleRightText!)
    items.append(triangleRightButton!)
    toolbar?.items = items
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar!)

    // self.view.bringSubview(toFront: toolbar!)

    // toolbar!.layer.zPosition = 1

    // Set colors for toolbar items and for toolbar:
    toolbar?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) //purple for toolbar items
    toolbar?.barTintColor = UIColor.white //white for toolbar color

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. You can add a button as `customview` and use the button action instead.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addtarget blablabla
uibarbuttonitem(customview: button)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this in mind. It certainly looks simple. I have no great urgency to change my existing code as another upgrade seems to have restored the original operability that I lost.